# Corporate proxy for iot-service-client azure-iot-sdk java

Tags: java, azure-iot-hub

I couldn't find an answer so my question is:
Is it possible to define an unauthenticated internal proxy for iot-service-client?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't supported yet, SDK release 1.21.